# Get Random Object From Array for Different ID Field C#

Tags: c#, object, random, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Object (C#). 
Each Object has in ID and a Value.

I need to get 1 Random object for Each ID.

Object Class is build in this Way

```
public class ObjectRandom
{
    int32 id { get; set; }
    string value { get; set;}
}
```

For Example This ArrayList has 6000 ObjectRandom.

*ID's COULD be sequential or not.*

So if there are 500 Objects For Each User that means there are 12 users. **(ID1 , ID2 , ID5 , ID10 , ID11, ID15 ID22 ETC).**

I would take from The ArrayList (that's Got ALL 6000 Objects) only **1** ObjectRandom **For Each ID's.**

Does it Possible? I'm trying without any result at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<ObjectRandom>()
    { 
        new ObjectRandom(){ id = 1, value = "a"},
        new ObjectRandom(){ id = 2, value = "b"},
        new ObjectRandom(){ id = 3, value = "c"},
        new ObjectRandom(){ id = 1, value = "d"},
        new ObjectRandom(){ id = 2, value = "e"},
        new ObjectRandom(){ id = 3, value = "f"},
    };
    var rnd = new Random();
    var q = from a in list.GroupBy (l => l.id)
            let col = a.ToList()
            select col[rnd.Next(0, col.Count)];
}

public class ObjectRandom 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set;}
}
```

If you need to use an ArrayList instead of a generic list use:

```
from a in list.Cast<ObjectRandom>().GroupBy (l => l.id)
```

Comment: It works good. I would ask you another thinkg. If i have inObjectRandom another field Like Type and i would take For Each id the Value of 1 Type. So i could have 2 results from the same user ,is it possible? Or do i have to Create More List for Each Type so i can use this algoritm with the Different List ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But you can group on both id and type. `list.GroupBy (l => new { l.id, l.Type })`

Comment: Yes you are right i havent explain well the situation. But,  that's what i needed. Group on both , i didnt know the syntax as well :) Thanks a lot man. Have a nice day!